# Получить координаты с экрана

Tags: python, координаты, мышь, курсор

Нужно получить координаты курсора по нажатию мыши. 
Координаты должны быть экранные а не привязаны к окну приложения. 
Подскажите решение или модуль, с помощью которого можно решить эту задачу.

Comment: легкий способ, это через pyautogui, для получения координат курсора pyautogui.position().
Подробнее можешь почитать на https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html.

Comment: pyautogui, pygame, tkinter, win32gui, win32api  https://www.google.com/search?q=python3+get+screen+mouse+coordinates

Comment: Благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно использовать библиотеку **pynput**

```py
from pynput import mouse

def on_mouse_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button == mouse.Button.left and pressed:
        print(f'X:{x} Y:{y}')

listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_mouse_click)
listener.start()
listener.join()
```